# Add capitalized letter after each dash in a string

Tags: javascript

Here is an example of what my problem is

```
let str = 'A-bb-cc-dd'
```

How do I make it so that the string will return

```
'A-Bb-Cc-Dd'
```

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Is that helped?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regex in a replace statement:

```js
let str = 'A-bb-cc-dd'

console.log(
  str.replace(/\-[a-z]/g, match => match.toUpperCase())
)
```

`\-[a-z]` will simply match a lowercase character after a dash, `match.toUpperCase()` makes all letters in the string uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JS [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and `String.replace` like so

```js
const result = 'A-bb-cc-dd'.replace(/(^\w|-\w)/g, c => c.toUpperCase());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,

```js
let str = 'A-bb-cc-dd';
let result = (str.split('-').map(e=>e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1))).join('-');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `split` by the string by `-` delimiter then use map to create a new array where the first character will be `uppercased` using `toUpperCase` and then use `join` to recreate the string

```js
let k = 'A-bb-cc-dd';
let convertedStr = k.split('-').map((item) => {
  return item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1);
}).join('-');
console.log(convertedStr)
```

```html
How do i make it so that the string will return 'A-Bb-Cc-Dd'
```

Comment: we're on the same track :)

Answer (score 0):

Use string split, map and join:

```js
let str = 'A-bb-cc-dd';
var array = str.split("-"); //console.log(array);
var result = array.map(current => {
    return current[0].toUpperCase() + current.substr(1);
});
var end = result.join("-");
console.log(end);
```