# Capitalize the string after hypen in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I would like to know how to capitalize the first letter after hypen in a string using javascript. If no hypen str should in lowercase

```js
var result = capitalize("js-script");

function capitalize(str){
 return str.split("-")[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ str.slice(1);
}
```

Expected Output:

```
js-script => js-Script  
tom => tom
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize hyphenated names in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504848/capitalize-hyphenated-names-in-javascript) and [Add capitalized letter after each dash in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a regular expression instead - match a `-` and an alphabetical character, and replace with a `-` and that word character, capitalized:

```js
const capitalize = (str) => str.replace(/-([a-z])/g, (_, char) => '-' + char.toUpperCase());

console.log(capitalize("js-script"));
console.log(capitalize("foo-bar-baz"));
```

To fix your original code, if there's only going to be one `-` in the input, you need to save the rest of the characters in the part after the `-` (not just the `charAt(0)`):

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  if (!str.includes('-')) {
    return str;
  }
  const [before, after] = str.split("-");
  return before + '-' + after.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);
}
console.log(capitalize('foo-bar'));
console.log(capitalize('foo'));
```

Comment: using `[a-z]` is better option than`\w` will try to change  `_ and digits` to uppercase which has no significance,

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex and look behind to do this:

```js
console.log(capitalize("js-script"));

function capitalize(str){
 return str.replace(/(?<=-)\w/g, (text) => text.toUpperCase());
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to escape the hyphen

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use regex and replace method

`-[a-z]`

- `-` - match character `-`
- `[a-z]` - match any character from a to z

```js
function capitalize(str){
 return typeof str === 'string' ? str.replace(/-([a-z])/gi,(m,g1)=> `-${g1.toUpperCase()}`) : str
}

console.log(capitalize("js-script"))
console.log( capitalize("tom"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```js
function capitalize(str){
  let arrSplit = str.split("-")
  let joinArray = [];
  for(var i=0;i<arrSplit.length;i++){
    if(i==0){
       joinArray.push(arrSplit[i]);
    }else{
      joinArray.push(arrSplit[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+arrSplit[i].slice(1));
    }
  }
 return joinArray.join("-",)
}

console.log(capitalize("js-script"))
console.log(capitalize("js-script-again"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```